# Connection error when call service inside a container from a python client inside another container

Tags: python, docker

I have two running docker containers in the same network. Following are parts the docker-compose file

```
service1:
    build:
      context: ./service1_code
    container_name: service1
    ports:
      - 5006:5005

python_client:
    build:
      context: ./python_client_code
    container_name: python_client
    ports:
    - 5008:5008
 restart: on-failure
```

I am sending a request from the client inside the **python_client** container to the service which is in **service1** container using the following code snippet

```
    data = {'abc':'xyz'}
    r = requests.post(url='http://service1:5005/xxx', data=data)
```

In the docker log I am getting the following error

```
python_client              | Traceback (most recent call last):
python_client              |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
python_client              |     timeout=timeout
python_client              |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
python_client              |     method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
python_client              |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 573, in increment
python_client              |     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
python_client              | urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='service1', port=5006): Max retries exceeded with url: /xxx (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6195ccc050>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Appreciate your insights in this matter

Comment: What code is running in the `service1` container?  Is it running a server listening on 0.0.0.0:5005?

Comment: Please use `0.0.0.0:[your port]`

Comment: @Suman I tried `requests.post(url='http://0.0.0.0:5005/xxx', data=data)` but it didn't work

Comment: Can we use team viwer or anydesk

Comment: @Malintha I did not receive anything. Please give me a link here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use localhost inside the container, you try to reach the container itself not possible to access another container. Use the service name instead or host IP to reach the container from a web browser. You should remove the link, it used to alias the service name.

```
http://service1:5005/test (from another container)
```